# Nuances between 災難 and 災い

Tags: word-choice, nuances

As the title says, I'm not sure of the difference between 災難 and 災い. Both seem to be mainly used for "personal" disasters (as opposed to 災害). There is a [GOO Thesaurus page](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/5330/meaning/m1u/%E7%81%BD%E5%AE%B3/), but it doesn't really help me here. It does indicate 犬にかまれるとはとんだ災難だ is natural but にかまれるとはとんだ災いだ is odd. Is there a reason for this?

Another more minor question: while the thesaurus indicates only 難 is used for Xの constructions for defining a type of disaster, I see many example sentences of the form 難を避けた, 難を免れた, and so on. Is "難を(escape-like word)" another specific pattern that is exclusive to 難? And are the Xの難 and 難をescape patterns the only way 難 is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some extent, they mean the same 'bad event', but

- 災い has religious/supernatural tone; it is more abstract and affects 'big' entities.
- 災難 is more concrete, personal bad luck.

Being bitten by a dog is too personal to be called 災い. And the influence of an earthquake is too big for 地震 to be called 災難.

Other than that, the difference is a matter of usage and collocation. 災難/災いに見舞われる (affected by something bad)  are both fine; In the following (randomly picked in BCCWJ), 災難 cannot be used.

- 助けを求めてエジプトに下り、馬に依り頼む者は災いだ *Woe to them that go down to Egypt for help; and stay on horses* (usage)
- 水辺で身体を清め、災いを祓う (religious)
- 大英帝国にとって災いの前兆であったのだ (big)
- パンドラの箱を開けてしまったが為に災いがこの世に飛び出す (abstract)
- 災い転じて福となす (fixed phrase)

災いだ is the opposite to *Blessed are...*; Also it is possible to say 災い+する to mean *affect negatively* while 災難する is ungrammatical.

---

For 難, I think it is used almost exclusively in combinations with verbs given in [the following](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%9B%A3/#jn-165581) (or verbs meaning very similar):

> １ 災い。災難。「あやうく―**を逃れる**」
> ２ むずかしいこと。むずかしさ。困難。「―**を避け**、易 (やす) きに就く」
> ３ 欠点。「少々―のある品」「強いて―**をいえ**ばやや甘さが足りない」
> ４ 非難すべき点。難点。「うかつだったとの―**を免か**れない」